# How do I summon entities in the direction my character is facing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to summon lightning from my server console so that it doesn't hit my player, but spawns where my player is facing. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If your server is 1.13+ minecraft, you can use [caret notation](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Tilde_and_caret_notation) and the [execute command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute). Using the command

```
/execute as <player> at @s run summon lightning_bolt ^ ^ ^5
```

would summon a lightning bolt five blocks in front of a player of your choosing. Keep in mind if the player is facing high up or down the lightning bolt will be in the ground or in the air.